# How does _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']) work?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, google-analytics

How does the Google Analytics Site Speed feature, `_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime'])`, work? Is there any documentation about how it works?

Comment: @stuken.yuri that's the syntax for the Google Analytics Asynchronous call. It basically means: add the function (name) `_trackPageLoadTime` onto a queue, and then fire all of the functions in that queue sequentially once ga.js has loaded. It allows you to safely load `ga.js` asynchronously.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

**Edit**: As of November 16th 2011, [the `_trackPageLoadTime` function has been deprecated and its functionality has been set as a default setting](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/community/gajs_changelog.html#release-2011-11). (Functionally speaking, it has gone from being an opt-in feature to being an opt-out feature.)

`_setSiteSpeedSampleRate` is the new function for setting the sample rate on this feature; its default value is `1` (as in 1%). To opt out of using this the Site Speed feature, you have to pass a `0` to this function:

```
_gaq.push(["_setSiteSpeedSampleRate", 0]);
```

---

From the [Google Analytics Help Center](http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205784&topic=1120718#setup):

> This report currently supports the
>   following browsers: Chrome, Internet
>   Explorer 9 and previous versions of
>   Internet Explorer with the Google
>   Toolbar installed. More specifically,
>   the Site Speed reports require
>   browsers that support the HTML5
>   NavigationTiming interface or have the
>   Google Internet Explorer toolbar
>   installed

So, it doesn't implement its own timer, like many prior homeback solutions had, to figure out how long it takes a page to load. Instead, it uses a new HTML5 feature, currently only supported in the above listed cases, called NavigationTiming.

**EDIT**: This is now supported in [Firefox 7](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/09/whats-new-for-web-developers-in-firefox-7/)

(Important to note that it doesn't run on every load; instead, it currently samples around 2% of pageviews, though it is configured to *try* to track all page loads on 10% of visits; as more browsers support the NavigationTiming API, you can expect the total sampled percentage to begin to get closer to 10%.)

This interface is accessed under the DOM object `window.performance` (or, in earlier versions of Chrome, `window.webkitPerformance`), using the `timing` attribute (so, `window.performance.timing`). The object stores measured values of all of the key page load event times, and Google Analytics subtracts 2 of the more important outer values to judge page load speed.

For a load of Mashable.com without cache, here's an example of what it measures (in Chrome 11):

```
timing = {
  connectEnd: 1306677079337,
  connectStart: 1306677079337,
  domComplete: 1306677083482,
  domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1306677081765,
  domContentLoadedEventStart: 1306677081576,
  domInteractive: 1306677081576,
  domLoading: 1306677079478,
  domainLookupEnd: 1306677079337,
  domainLookupStart: 1306677079337,
  fetchStart: 1306677079337,
  loadEventEnd: 1306677083483,
  loadEventStart: 1306677083482,
  navigationStart: 1306677079337,
  redirectEnd: 0,
  redirectStart: 0,
  requestStart: 1306677079394,
  responseEnd: 1306677079669,
  responseStart: 1306677079476,
  secureConnectionStart: 0,
  unloadEventEnd: 0,
  unloadEventStart: 0
}
```

Those numbers are epoch milliseconds, or milliseconds since January 1, 1970. I have not seen any documentation as to which values they subtract to generate their values, but from a cursory inspection of the [ga.js](http://google-analytics.com/ga.js), it looks like it is `loadEventStart-fetchStart`:

```
h&&h[c]!=k&&h.isValidLoadTime?b=h[c]:e&&e[a]&&(b=e[a].loadEventStart-e[a].fetchStart);
```

For the above sample, that means it would record **4.14 seconds** in the `_trackPageLoadTime` call.

#### From the W3C Navigation Timing spec:

> [**fetchStart attribute**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-navigation-timing-20101026/#nt-fetch-start)
>
> If the new
>   resource is to be fetched using HTTP
>   GET or equivalent, fetchStart must
>   return the time immediately before the
>   user agent starts checking any
>   relevant application caches.
>   Otherwise, it must return the time
>   when the user agent starts fetching
>   the resource.
>
> [**loadEventStart attribute**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-navigation-timing-20101026/#nt-load-start)
>
> This
>   attribute must return the time
>   immediately before the load event of
>   the the current document is fired. It
>   must return zero when the load event
>   is not fired yet.

For curious parties, the ordering appears to be as follows:

> connectStart, connectEnd,
>   domainLookupStart, domainLookupEnd,
>   fetchStart, navigationStart,
>   requestStart, responseStart,
>   domLoading, responseEnd,
>   domContentLoadedEventStart,
>   domInteractive,
>   domContentLoadedEventEnd, domComplete,
>   loadEventStart, loadEventEnd

For the 0 values listed:

`unloadEventStart` and `unloadEventStart` show the times for the previous page load's unloading (but only if that page has the same origin as the current one.)

`redirectEnd` and `redirectStart` measure the latency added if there was an HTTP redirect in the page load chain.

`secureConnectionStart` appears to be an optional measurement for measuring the SSL connection time.

Comment: You rock dude, seriously.  Thanks for such an elaborate response.

Comment: `secureConnectionStart` is a standard mesurement, but it is optional for the browser (or whatever handles the content) to report.  http://w3c-test.org/webperf/specs/NavigationTiming/#nt-secure-connect-start