# Google Analytics: Site Speed average always at 0.00

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed

I have the following code (obviously the XX has a real number):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX']);
   _gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 10]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I have an average of 1000 hits per day. Yet, I see the average load time speed at 0 sec for all pages. I integrated this 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have _setSiteSpeedSampleRate set with my GA code, but I do have all the stats in my reports. You may want to remove it entirely.

See this post for a more detailed answer about how _setSiteSpeedSampleRate used to work: [How does _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166074/how-does-gaq-push-trackpageloadtime-work)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the sample rate to 100% and Google Analytics will then keep as amny samples as it can.

What browsers are you seeing visit your site - Site Speed only works with browsers that support the Navigation Timing API i.e. Chrome, Friefox, IE9

Answer (score 3):

Your tracking code looks fine. As Andy already mentioned, you can set your sampling rate to 100%, since the overall amount of traffic you're seeing is below 10K visits/day. To do so, simply change the 10 to 100 in the second `_gaq.push`.