# How does jQuery.load() Affect Page Loads in Google Analytics?

Tags: jquery, pageload, page-load-time

I curious to know how the jQuery.load functionality affects page load speeds when reporting to Google Analytics? Does that load time, which should be loading external scripts after the whole page is done loading, count as actual page load time when kicking back to the mothership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling load from e.g. .ready, in response to a click etc?

Here's a good post on the mechanics of how GA measures page load time - [How does _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166074/how-does-gaq-push-trackpageloadtime-work)

Basically it's up until the load event fires, anything after isn't countec.