# Does google measure page load on push state?

Tags: google-analytics, pushstate, load-time

I'm currently working on a website which is structured as a single page app (loads everything in once). The site relies on the pushState api in order to function and of course for analytics purposes we correctly track the user on these events so our views are accurate.

What I am wondering though, as it's currently my main focus, is whether google analytics is measuring page load when these page tracking events occur? And if so how exactly does it calculate the load time in this circumstance. (I know on initial page load it will use the navigation API)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does \_gaq.push(\['\_trackPageLoadTime'\]) work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166074/how-does-gaq-push-trackpageloadtime-work)

Comment: Sadly not. That is an old deprecated way of telling Google to track your timings.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en

> Site speed tracking occurs only for visits from those browsers that
>   support the HTML5 `Navigation Timing` interface or have the Google
>   Toolbar installed. Typically this includes: Chrome, Firefox 7 and
>   above, Internet Explorer 9 and above, Android 4.0 browser and above,
>   as well as earlier versions of Internet Explorer with the Google
>   Toolbar installed.

So it will measure timing accurately regardless of how you load the tag since it uses the browser API `window.performance.timing`.

More about the `Navigation Timing` API:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing
- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html

Comment: Thanks for responding but sadly this doesn't answer the question! We know the performance timing api is used to measure your first page load time but do not know if it would then try any other timings when the user is browsing through the site all via the pushstate api. Atm the assumption is it doesn't and that only the initial page request and load is measured.